# ASP.Net Core Area Routing without AreaAttribute with default routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a problem regarding AreaRouting in my ASP.Net Core MVC project. I want to use Area routing without adding AreaAttribute for each controller (I move from an existing ASP.NET MVC 5 project with hundreds of controller and adding this attribute is really cumbersome)

My sample application folder structure looks like this:
[image]

The namespaces follow the folder structure.
I found a way to add a custom convention and extract the area name:

```
internal sealed class AreaRoutingConvention : IControllerModelConvention
    {
        public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
        {
            var hasRouteAttributes = controller.Selectors.Any(selector => selector.AttributeRouteModel != null);

            if (hasRouteAttributes)
            {
                return;
            }

            var controllerTypeNamespace = controller.ControllerType.Namespace;
            if (controllerTypeNamespace == null)
                return;

            var areaName = controllerTypeNamespace.Split('.').SkipWhile(segment => segment != "Areas").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();

            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(areaName))
            {
                var template = areaName + "/[controller]/[action]/{id?}";
                controller.RouteValues.Add("area", areaName);

                foreach (var selector in controller.Selectors)
                {
                    selector.AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                    {
                        Template = template
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My sample route configuration is this one:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                    name: "Activity_default",
                    areaName: "Activity",
                    "Activity/{controller=Activity}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Activity", action = "Index" }
                );
                
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                    name: "Admin_default",
                    areaName: "Admin",
                    "Admin/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" }
                );

                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                    name: "home_default",
                    areaName: "Home",
                    pattern: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

It works in almost all of my cases:
Now when I enter

- /Activity/Activity/Index -> Index method is invoked
- /Activity/Home/Index -> Not found, as intended
- /Home/Home/Index -> Index method is invoked
- /Home/Activity/Index -> Not found, as intended
- /Admin/Admin/Index -> Index method is invoked
- /Admin/Activity/Index -> Not found, as intended

But I also want to route to the /Activity/Activity/Index method when the user enters

- /Activity
- /Activity/Activit/

Can anyone please help with this problem? When I do not use my custom convention and add Area-Attributes to the controllers all works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try route attributes

```
public partial class ActivityController : Controller
    {

        [Route("~/Activity")]
        [Route("~/Activity/Activity")]
        [Route("~/Activity/Activity/Index")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ....
        }
```